# What changes to the story/narration are there in New Game+?

Tags: bastion

*Warning: potential spoilers if you've not finished at least once*

So I've been playing through New Game+ in Bastion, I'm on the 3rd or 4th Shard now so quite far.

At the start of the game, and I mean *right* at the start, I heard an echo of Rucks saying "Maybe I'll see you in the next one" before his first speech, which I believe was the last thing he said at the end of the Restoration finale.

Then, when entering the saloon later in the wharf, Rucks interrupts himself when talking about the bar keep and mumbles something before continuing - having a deja vu moment it seems.

Because of these two I was then expecting more of these references to the time loop throughout the game, but I haven't noticed any others. Have I missed them, are there only these two, or are there more to come at the end?

Comment: As I played through New Game Plus, I too noticed remarks such as that too.  But nothing significantly different from the normal game as far as I can remember.

Comment: I have yet to beat the game (although I am close), but your two examples are all I've noticed so far as well. I'll report back once I do beat the game.

Comment: ...and second play-through is complete!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following list of locations is where I heard something that sounded distinctly different than the first play-through:

- Introduction Sequence
- The Sole Regret (bar at the end of the Wharf District, the first level)
- Urzendra Gate (the level after you collect the 6th shard)

Each narration change was minor and didn't add much to the plot. If there were others, they were subtle enough that I missed them.

A free DLC, [released on 14th December](http://store.steampowered.com/news/6993/) on Steam, added new features in New Game+ mode:

- The Stranger’s Dream: a new fully narrated Who Knows Where sequence, bigger and tougher than the others.
- Score Attack Mode: a challenging new way to play through the story! You start at level one with all Spirits and Idols unlocked. Combat performance is rated for efficiency, and all areas are repeatable

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't expecting huge changes, but it's nice to know I haven't missed much. :)

Answer (score 4):

When you first see Zulf in the Hanging Gardens, Rucks says "Something so familiar about that man." instead of the original narration.